# .resx file not found. Programming error or something else? ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, resx

everyone, I've been struggling with this for a long time.

ONLY IN PRODUCTION, it happens that the resource files are not found during the compilation of the page.

This happens every now and then, at irregular intervals, even after months.

When it happens, just restart the iis pool and everything works again, can anyone tell me what happens?

---

CODE:

```
Private Sub CreaStrumentiSopra()
    Dim lbl2 As New Label
    lbl2.Attributes.Add("class", "lblNumeroProdottiTrovati")
    If (conteggioProdotti = 1) Then
        lbl2.Text = " " & GetLocalResourceObject("lblProdotto")
    Else
        lbl2.Text = " " & GetLocalResourceObject("lblProdotti")
    End If
    panStrumenti.Controls.Add(lbl2)
End Sub
```

---

```
Error 500
Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
Inner Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The resource class for this page was not found.  Please check if the resource file exists and try again.
   at System.Web.Compilation.LocalResXResourceProvider.CreateResourceManager()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BaseResXResourceProvider.EnsureResourceManager()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BaseResXResourceProvider.GetObject(String resourceKey, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Web.Compilation.ResourceExpressionBuilder.GetResourceObject(IResourceProvider resourceProvider, String resourceKey, CultureInfo culture, Type objType, String propName)
   at System.Web.Compilation.ResourceExpressionBuilder.GetResourceObject(IResourceProvider resourceProvider, String resourceKey, CultureInfo culture)
   at pCatalogo.CreaStrumentiSopra()
   at pCatalogo.CreateChildControls()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: Hai provato ad eliminare la cartella 'bin' ed 'obj' prima di compilare/pubblicare?

Comment: Hi, maybe I expressed myself badly.

The error does not happen on the first compilation.
I simply see in the logs:
System.Web.Compilation.LocalResXResourceProvider.CreateResourceManager ()

So, the page is accessible and working up to two seconds before and then it just doesn't find the .resx files anymore until I restart the pool

Comment: Ciao, forse mi sono espresso male.

L'errore non capita alla prima compilazione. 
Semplicemente vedo nei log:
System.Web.Compilation.LocalResXResourceProvider.CreateResourceManager()

Quindi, la pagina è accessibile e funzionante fino a due secondi prima e poi basta non trova più i file .resx fin quando non riavvio il pool

Comment: Se nella compilazione ci va a finire delle risorse incorporate di qualsiasi natura ti consiglio di eliminare la cartella ‘obj’ e ‘bin’ e poi ripubblicare. Rimuovi tutto dal host e rimetti le versioni nuove, appena compilate, (immagino il sito gira come una .dll ).

Comment: Se questo non funziona (anche perchè sembra strano che rifunziona dopo il riavvio) opterei per qualche aggiornamento del IIS (l’unica cosa che mi viene in mente)

Comment: Potrebbe essere che i file vengano messi in lock da qualche processo ? o da IIS stesso? La prossima volta che accade questo vorrei provare a verificarlo. Anche se in quel caso l'errore dovrebbe appunto risultare diverso.

Comment: I file .resx comunque stanno nelle cartelle App_LocalResources e App_GlobalResources. (almeno quelli dove si presenta l'errore gli altri stanno sul bin). La versione di IIS invece è la 10.0

Comment: Si sono quelle ma se stai cercando di prendere delle risorse via codice a volte puo’ essere anche mal intrepretato il percorso,  
Puo bastare togliere il tilde oppure es: ~/App_LocalResources/Default.aspx deve diventare ~/Default.aspx in quanto IIS sa dove stanno e aggiunge di suo il preffisso App_Resources

Comment: Non c'è nessuna tilde, viene utilizzato questo metodo: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.templatecontrol.getlocalresourceobject?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: You can use FRT to troubleshoot this issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis